# Is there a way to open a linked workbook in Excel using Office.js?

Tags: excel, office-js, office-addins, excel-addins, excel-web-addins

I am trying to programmatically open a linked workbook referenced in the current workbook in Excel using the Office.js framework. I see an [Excel.LinkedWorkbook class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/excel/excel.linkedworkbook?view=excel-js-preview) but with no function to open the linked workbook. How would I do this?

Comment: This cannot be done at the present time. You can suggest this at [Microsoft 365 Developer Platform Ideas!](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-365-developer-platform/idb-p/Microsoft365DeveloperPlatform)